# Magento 2.0.7 sitemap not display?

Tags: magento2, sitemaps

I am new to magento 2.x. I have created sitemap.xml, but it's not display in frontend. how to get sitemap url?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's no HTML sitemap available for Magento 2 by default. You need to use extension for it or you can customize it yourself.

Comment: thank for your reply. i will check

Comment: Can you please tell me, how to customize?